# A place that I will like or would like?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

> If you take me to a place that I **would** like, I will give you this.
>   If you take me to a place that I **will** like, I will give this.

Or simply

> Take me to a place that I **would** like.
>   Take me to a place that I **will** like.

Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct and are almost identical, but there is a subtle distinction:

- "Would" implies that there is some doubt: "... a place that I [most probably] will like."
- "Will" implies more certainty: "... a place that I [certainly] will like."

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Will_and_would